# How to use wreq to download only part of response?

Tags: http, haskell, request, streaming

How can I download only the first 1 KiB of the response using [wreq](http://www.serpentine.com/wreq/) library?

Theoretically I could use the `Range` HTTP header. However, that requires support on the server, which I can't rely on.

How can I abort the request once I have enough data on the client?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use the [foldGet](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/wreq-0.4.1.0/docs/Network-Wreq.html#v:foldGet) function, accumulate chunks of data as they arrive, and throw an exception once enough data has been downloaded. The accumulated data will be passed out in the exception.

```
import qualified Control.Exception           as E
import qualified Data.ByteString             as BS
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy        as BL
import           Data.ByteString.Builder

data EnoughException = Enough Builder

instance Show EnoughException where
    show _ = "EnoughException"

instance E.Exception EnoughException

getFile :: Int -> String -> IO BL.ByteString
getFile maxLen url = ((extract . fst) <$> foldGet process (mempty, 0) url) `E.catch` enough
  where
    extract :: Builder -> String
    extract = BL.take (fromIntegral maxLen) . toLazyByteString

    process :: (Builder, Int)   -- ^(Accumulated data, current length)
            -> BS.ByteString    -- ^Downloded chunk
            -> IO (Builder, Int)
    process (acc, cur) now = do
        let acc' = acc <> byteString now
        let cur' = cur + BS.length now
        if cur' > maxLen
            then E.throw (Enough acc')
            else return (acc', cur')

    enough (Enough d) = return (extract d)
```

(Note: this function does not handle exceptions that could be thrown by *wreq*. For real use that would be necessary.)

Comment: @ErikAllik Probably is. I'm open to suggestions. Also, feel free to edit and improve :)